# Как называется следующая конструкция?

Tags: c++, c

В моем коде есть следующая конструкция:

`A_name::B_name::Name *test_name=A_name::B_name::name();`

A_name, В_name определен в следующем в виде:

```
namespace A_name{
        namespace B_name{
        --//--
        }
}
```

Прошу дать полный и развернутый ответ по этому поводу.

Comment: [Пространствами имён](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/namespaces-cpp?view=vs-2019) называется.

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен. Не может быть никакого осмысленного толкования данной "конструкции" без полной информации о ее элементах. Что такое `Name`? Что такое `name`? Почему в тексте вопроса отсутствует эта информация?

Comment: Я сам хочу узнать Что такое ```A_name```, ```B_name`` ```Name```?

Comment: Ым... Откуда мы может знать, что такое `Name` если вы - автор вопроса(!) - не предоставили о нем вообще никакой информации??? Без конкретной информации о том, что такое `Name`, `name` и `test_name` никакого осмысленного ответа на этот вопрос быть не может.

Comment: **Мною допущена ошибка необходим пробел после** ```Name``` И так имеется ```A_name::B_name::Name *test_name=A_name::B_name::name();``` Напоминаю что: ```A_name``` пространство имен в который вложено пространство имен ```B_name```, а ```Name``` структура внутри последнего.  ```*test_name``` как я понял это указатель(переменная). Я правильно мыслю насчет указателя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разберу по прядку:

1. `::` – оператор доступа к области видимости, позволяет "увидеть" то,
   что скрыто под `namespace`-ом или в классе
2. Итак, мы получаем доступ к тому, что объявлено пространстве имён
   `A_name`, среди прочего там есть и пространство `B_name`
3. Далее, мы получаем доступ к тому, что объявлено в пространстве имён
   `B_name`, а там, среди прочего, есть класс `Name`
4. Объявляем переменную-указатель на объект класса `Name` с названием
   `test_name`
5. Далее читаем с конца: как видно, в том же пространстве имён есть
   некая функция, по всей видимости, возвращающая указатель объект
   класса `Name` (откуда такие предположения о возвращаемом значении –
   читайте далее)
6. Возвращаемое значение этой функции сохраняется в переменную
   `test_name` (т.к. её тип – тип "левого" значения – `Name*`, то и тип
   возвращаемого значения функции должен быть такого же типа или типа,
   унаследованного от этого, иначе была бы ошибка типизации)

Таким образом, мы просто создаём и инициализируем переменную `test_name`, имеющую тип `Name*`.

Сложности восприятия здесь создают пространства имён, чтобы избавиться от этого, код можно переписать так:

```cpp
using namespace A_name::B_name;

Name* test_name = name();
```

P.S. Под классом здесь может подразумеваться любая сущность, обозначающая тип. Например, структура.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что `Name`  является классом, а не чем-то другим? Формально это может быть даже именем переменной, а `*` - оператором умножения. С чего вы взяли, что `name`  - это функция, а не, скажем, имя типа?

Comment: @AnT Тогда получилось бы, что что-то присваивается перемножению переменных. Появится ошибка "Выражение должно быть допустимо для изменения левосторонним значением". Однако насчёт необязательности класса Вы правы.

Comment: Очень подробно объяснил Чрезмерно благодарен!

Comment: @NoJS Всегда рад помочь.

Comment: @V-Mor: Ну здрасьте! Почему вы решили, что результат оператора `*` не может быть "левосторонним значением"? И почему вы решили, что "левостороннее значение" тут вообще требуется? Не забываем, что это вопрос по языку С++. Смотрим сюда: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/451395f32eb64d5f. В этом коде `name` - имя класса, `Name` и `test_name` - имена переменных, а `*` - именно оператор умножения. Где вы тут видите ошибку "Выражение должно быть допустимо для изменения левосторонним значением"?

Comment: @AnT по крайней мере, это гораздо менее осмысленно, а следовательно, и менее вероятно.

Comment: @V-Mor: Нет, ни в коем случае. "Осмысленность" этих конструкций совершенно одинакова и встречаются они постоянно и повсеместно. И никакого "вероятно" тут нет и быть не может. Это исходный вопрос, еще раз, поставлен бессмысленно. В результате мы имеем еще одну пару "низкокачественный вопрос - низкокачественный ответ".

Comment: @AnT Ну, что я могу сказать: спорить бессмысленно, Ваше мнение, несомненно, тоже имеет место быть. Человеку я помог, как видите, на этом и закончим.